# How to stop Feedreader fetching content from my site using iFrame?

Tags: duplicate-content, iframe

As you all can see from the picture below, my site's content is duplicated by FeedReader (using iFrame) and indexed at Google. When I clicked at the FeedReader link, it uses some sort of iFrame to draw content from my site live. At the meantime, my site traffic has dropped significantly, but I not sure if this is the reason.

https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-hc4pVwHvQoo/UGGcwVyRqYI/AAAAAAAAAIc/9m04UOwmfEk/s1600/1.PNG

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-ljj6dV7xTik/UGGc0x4GiZI/AAAAAAAAAIk/3mZ6HiCiQ2w/s1600/2.PNG

What can I do to prevent Feedreader to fetch my content to their site? Any help would be much appreciated. By the way, I'm using wordpress as my CMS.

I have also highlighted this issue to FeedReader 2 days ago, but yet to get any reply from them.

Answer (score 1):

Write a simple plugin to break out of the FeedReader frame.

Sample code, not tested:

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: FeedReader Frame Buster */

add_action( 'wp_head', 'wm_34968_feedreader_frame_buster' );

function wm_34968_feedreader_frame_buster()
{
?>
<script>if (document.referrer.indexOf('feedreader.com') && (self != top)) {
    top.location.replace(self.location.href);
}</script>
<?php
}
```

That will not stop the indexing, but your visitors will get an unframed experience. :)